# How to enable "Play 2 App" in Jetbrains IntelliJ Run Configuration

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, ide, intellij-plugin

I've download the Scala plugin and imported an activator application into IntelliJ, but all tutorials and how-to's online and on StackOverflow say to choose "Play 2 App",  but it's simply not there.

What am I missing?

**Versions**:

- IntelliJ IDEA: 15.0.2
- Scala Plugin: 2.0.4

Comment: I think play support is only available in the paid version, are you sure you are not using the community edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @pedrofurla you are right. With community edition you will not have feature in your IntelliJ IDEA to create Play Application directly.

If you wish to create Play application make sure you have downloaded [Typesafe Activator](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/download). GOTO cmd prompt and then simply run below command,

1. "activator new"
2. Select option 6 for Play and Scala App
3. Give your application name and you are done with it
4. Now open your IntelliJ IDEA
5. GOTO File Menu `-->` Open `-->` then select your project and checked option "Auto import"
6. click on "OK".

Once you perform above steps it will download some dependency and will take some time to prepare your app.

Once process complete from your project path execute "activator run" command and open http://localhost:9000 to check everything works fine and test your app.

Comment: I already had this method working. Was interested in running the app without opening another window. I'll give you the Answer however what i did is create a run.bat file with "activator run" in it. Installed the CMD and Batch Script Intellij Plugins and could run the "run.bat" inside Intellij itself by double-clicking it or choosing it as a run-config. This allowed the activator to run inside Intellij and no external cmd window.